# HTTPS redirects to totally different website?

Tags: http, redirect, https, http-headers

I am doing some minor changes on my friends website. I noticed something very weird: when address is: https://websitename.com , it leads visitor to totally different website (and in address line is still https://websitename.com address, with notification about bad ssl sertificate), selling some shoes or something. http is still ok.

Site is checked for viruses, computers also, twice, and nothing is found. What could possbly cause this?

Website is hosted on Hostgator.

EDIT: I have to mention that i have address of "wrong" website. When I go to it, it shows empty page, and there is nothing on that domain. Like https://mywebsite.com is pointing to some website that is cached somewhere.

EDIT2: Also, there is a problem with google, he indexed https version of website, and found some links on "wrong" website, and indexed them too. So now, I can google https://mywebsite.com/something/shoe , and that page does not exists on http (giving 404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its a hosting issue. I had similar problem with subdomains, when on one of my subdomains completely different site appeared.

Its due to on 1 server (ip) there are more than 1 domain (shared hosting) and it might be not configured properly. Ask your hosting provider support how they would explain and fix it, as this is obviously big security issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer orsz. I have a question.. Is this normal, or would be possible that this be a malicious act? Like host wants to benefit another website against my (static) website?